# Keeping a variable's original value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, parallax

So I'm working on a plugin of sorts, and one of the things I need to do is get the position if it has been set in CSS.

So lets say in the CSS the person has down this:

```
position: relative;
top: 100px;
```

I need to get the 100px bit. That's easy enough!

```
var topMove = parseFloat($('#menu-complete').css('top'));
```

Later on I change the position of item.

```
        var positionMovedMenu = (-(scroll * 1.4) + topMove);
    $('#menu-complete').css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : positionMovedMenu+'px'});
```

Unfortunately this changes the value of the topMove variable, since the CSS value 'top' has changed. How can I store the original value?

Comment: `topMove` hasn't changed; the value of `$('#menu-complete').css('top')` has changed. As long as you don't set `topMove` equal to anything else, you've already got the original value stored.

Comment: Sorry! I misread that. Basically my question is, how can I store the original value of $('#menu-complete').css('top') without it changing. The value changes because I'm moving the things around.

Comment: use `alert()` or `console.log` to make sure `topMove` is what you expect when you expect it. Your problem might actually be between the above lines of code. Can you show us more of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a global variable an object to hold that information easy enough.  If you have multiple values, I would suggest storing them in object format.

Comment: I managed to work it out. It was a problem with my code. Thanks anyway!